# html table with first column fixed that accommodates different length of data

Tags: css, scroll, html-table, fixed-width

fiddle here 
https://jsfiddle.net/f2w8ga0t/

html

```
<table id="AnalyticalDataGrid">
  <tbody>   
    <tr>                                                                    <td>gdfgdfgdfgdfg</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>999</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>                                                                    <td>gfhgfhy7567567567</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>999</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>                                                                    <td>fsdfsd</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>777</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css

```
table#AnalyticalDataGrid {
   table-layout: fixed; 
   border-collapse: separate; 
   width: 100%;
}


table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr td {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #e1e3fe;
}

table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #FFF;
}

table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr:first-child, table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(2), table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: rgb(51, 122, 182);
    color: white;
}


table#AnalyticalDataGrid tbody tr td:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(51, 122, 182);
    color: white;
    text-align: left;   
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I need to have the first column fixed and the rest of the table with horizontal scroll, pretty standard request. The issue is that if the data in the first column too long, the first column gets written on top of the next, is there any way to have the second column relative to the first?